# connect a react hooks components that is not have a parent and child connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, show-hide

i want to connect a react components, that doesn't have a parent and child connection, but i want to show and hide from the child of another components.

here it is the code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import DashSidebar from "./DashSidebar";
import Catalog from "./components/catalog";

function Dashboard() {
  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = "Home";
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="l-dashboard">
      <DashSidebar />
      <Catalog />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

i have a button in `DashSidebar` and i want to show and hide `Catalog`

why i don't make it parent and child ?

because  `DashSidebar` is a fixed position, and it is a side panel to the left, while i want to show and hide the content in the right side..

[image]

Comment: are you using react router ?

Comment: yes i use it, in the parent of this components

Comment: can it be done using react router ? and if it can can you put a link on the doc

Comment: you can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1):

since you are using `react-router` this can be done with the below steps.

1. Wrap your Catalog list in the side bar with the `Link` component .
2. Now render the Catalog on the right with the help of `Route` .

Please refer the sandbox

[React SideBar Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-chaplygin-l9kf4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: then how do you connect it to the catalog A, catalog B, etc ?

Comment: I assume by catalog A and catalog B you refer to the items in side Bar ? . Is that correct ? . You need to wrap the Catalog item with a Link Component . So that when you click on `catalogA` your route will change to `..../catalogA` . when you click `catalogB` your route will change to `..../catalogB` . Now inside the  `<Catalog />` component you can add a `<Route path="/catalogA" component={CatalogAComponent} />` .

Comment: for confitming some stuff  should pass Link to sidebar right ?

Comment: ```import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <>
        <SideBar />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Nope its not needed , can you paste the code on how you are rendering the catalogA, catalogB etc ? Its difficult to help on assumptions .

Comment: ```
const types = ['Catalog A', 'Catalog B', 'Catalog C', 'Catalog D'];


export default function CatalogItems( {title, children, visible, setVisibility, props }) {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(visible?true:false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(visible) {
            setShow(true);
        } else {
            const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                setShow(false);
            }, 500)
            return () => {clearTimeout(timeout)};
        }
    }, [visible])

    const [active, setActive] = useState(types[0]);
```

Comment: ```
        <div className={`catalog-container${visible?"":" hidden"}`} 
        ><ButtonGroup>{types.map(type => (
                        <ButtonToggle
                        key={type}
                        active={active === type}
                        onClick={() => setActive(type)} 
                        show={parseFloat(show)}
                        >
                        {type}
                        <p>
                            Unpublished
                        </p>
                        </ButtonToggle>              ))}</ButtonGroup></div>
```

Comment: can you add it in the question , it is difficult to read from the comments .

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/muhzulzidan/testing/main/DashSidebar.js

Answer (score 0):

[Lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) of the Catalog's visibility to the Dashboard component by passing a function in DashSidebar's props that changes a variable in Dashboard's state. Pass the variable in Catalog's props to control its visibility.